# How can I check whether a string contains a given string, that is not a part of another given string?

Tags: java, string

For instance, I have this string: `hello world, you're full of weird things`

I'd like to know whether this string contains a `ll` **that's not a part of the string `hell`**, aka it should return true in this example, because there's a `ll` in the word `full`;

If the string was only `hello world`, it wouldn't match, since the `ll` in `hello` is a part of the given `hell` string

Comment: There's nothing better than being downvoted with no comments

Comment: Do want return true if a string has multiple occurrences of another string right?

Comment: @SumeshTG correct (so I imagine we could just stop searching after the first result is found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
String mainString = "hello world, you're full of weird things";
String findString = "ll";
String removeString = "hell";

String newString = mainString.Remove(mainString.IndexOf(removeString), removeString.Length);

if (newString.Contains(findString))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, your method is brilliant. Side-note: this question is tagged with Java, I ended up using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.remove(mainString, notInString).contains(findString)`

Comment: Ah, so sorry. I tried to answer as quickly as possible and forgot to look to tags. If you want I can add Java code to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean checkOccurance(String str,String findStr,,String butNotIn ){
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;
        str = str.replace(butNotIn,"");
        while(lastIndex != -1){

            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

            if(lastIndex != -1){
                count ++;
                lastIndex += findStr.length();
            }
        }
        if(count>1){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
```

call the method

```
System.out.println( checkOccurance("hello world, you're full of weird things","ll","hell"));
```

output

```
false
```

Comment: I don't see the `hell` string here anywhere, I imagine this thing as a method like
`boolean contains(String in, String toFind, String butNotIn)`.

Comment: You can convert this snippet as a method with parameters and return as boolean. I have shown the logic only.

Comment: But where does it take `hell` into consideration (read the question fully again)

Comment: Ya @Nicofisi sorry for misunderstanding. Now try this answer.

Comment: There is no need to loop on the `lastIndex`, just test the index after replacing the string : `return str.replace(butNotIn,"").indexOf(findStr)>-1`

Answer (score 1):

You could use *RegExp* and [Negative Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
public static boolean matches(String str) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!he)ll");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

**Test:**

```
    System.out.println(matches("hello world, you're full of weird things"));    // true
    System.out.println(matches("hello world")); // false
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Z3JlYz/1)

Comment: This method is performance critical so I'm still open to any non-regex solutions, but yes - this does exactly what I wanted it to, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to find the boundary (start and end index) of the `butNotIn` then use `String#indexOf` until you have an index that is outside the boundary ?

```
boolean isIn(String string, String word, String butNotIn) {
  int start = string.indexOf(butNotIn);
  int end = start+butNotIn.length;

  int position;
  do {
    position = string.indexOf(word);
  } while (position<start || position>end);
  return position>-1;
}
```

Comment: I think this showed me some good direction, although the `butNotIn` can occur multiple times; let me experiment with this idea for a moment